# ImportError: No module named 'flask' python3 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, flask, ubuntu-16.04

```
< mod_wsgi cannot import flask.
```

I did not install flask under a `virtualenv`. I can import flask using a python shell just fine. I edited my virtualhost config to contain `WSGIDaemonProcess HRApp user=USER group=GROUP python-path=/home/USER/.local/bin/python3.5/site-packages` to no avail. What am I missing?

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__
'1.0.2'
>>>
```

apache config:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess HRApp user=USER group=GROUP python-path=/home/USER/.local/bin/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/file.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/appname>
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "USER"
            AuthUserFile "/passwords_file"
            Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Is mod_wsgi running under your user?

Comment: Yes. Edited my question to include my apache config. WSGIDaemonProcess has the correct username @JaredSmith

Comment: in your command line, check the path of flask by doing `flask.__file__` and see if the path matches with you config

Comment: output of flask.__file__: '/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/__init__.py' @mckuok

Comment: So the output of `flask.__file__` is different from the `python-path` config, maybe match the 2 and see if it helps?

Comment: i.e. `python-path=/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: changed it to read: `WSGIDaemonProcess HRApp user=USER group=GROUP python-path=/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` no change in behavior after restarting apache @mckuok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by installing a virtualenv in the Flask app's root folder and then pointing mod_wsgi to that as the python installation with `WSGIPythonHome`